# Flutter - how to change widget every time the data changes

Tags: flutter

In my Flutter app I've got a widget with a text. The text simply displays a string but the string is in a completly different widget in a different class. The string changes its value over time and I want the widget with the text to update every time the string changes. What should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a completely different class then you can save your data in `sharedpreferences` whenever it changes and then call it on the `initState` of the other class.

OR
go for [providers](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)

Detail article on provider can be found [Here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/making-sense-all-of-those-flutter-providers-e842e18f45dd)

Comment: But will the text change every time the data changes? Thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

I'd share a cubit/bloc between the two widgets and use that to convey information.

Check out the [flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) package.

Comment: Thaks for advice, but I think I will use the provider.